# What's the simplest way to run a node.js script periodically on Google's Cloud Platform?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, google-api-nodejs-client

I've written a node js script that does a scraping job (selenium) and logs the results to Google sheets (Google sheets api). I need to make the script run completely automatically- not me running it daily on my system. What would be the simplest way to put this on Google Cloud and automate it to run periodically- say twice a day? I've taken a trial package of Google Cloud, but am not really familiar with the services so I'm not sure what would be the right choice for me.

Disclaimers: I'm not really a programmer- more of a hobbyist thus, technical complexity can be moderate at best and second. I'd need help with setting up the environment as well so walkthroughs or examples would really help.

Comment: Google Cloud Functions have a scheduling function in alpha at the moment, so if you can wait, I'd wait for that as it will likely be easy to use else you could try and sign up for the alpha - see lower half of this article: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/cloud-functions-serverless-platform-is-generally-available

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart) on how to deploy Node.js in App Engine.
This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron) as well covers how to automate jobs on App Engine using Cron for Java.

Hope it helps.